# Converting between two types in c

Tags: c, types

I have data of type `char data[500];` which I need to put into a function which takes `unsigned char* data`. How can I convert between the two? I'm a c noob.

Answer (score 3):

You can Simply type cast to `unsigned char`
Here is an example

```
void method(unsigned char *data)
{
    printf("%c",*(data+5));
}
int main()
{
  char arr[10];
  arr[5] = 's';
  method((unsigned char*)arr);
}
```

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 2):

One of the following should work.

1. Cast the data before calling the function.

   ```
   char data[500];
   function((unsigned char*)data);
   ```
2. Copy the data before calling the function.

   ```
   unsigned char copyOfData[500];
   memcpy(copyOfData, data, 500);
   function(copyOfData);
   ```
3. Start with `unsigned char` data type.

   ```
   unsigned char data[500];
   function(data);
   ```

Comment: None of those converts, they all reinterpret the data.

Comment: @2501, If type of `data` cannot be changed, there is no other option.

Comment: @2501 OP didn't ask to convert the data;  he asked how to convert the expression `data` to a form which is compatible with `unsigned char *`. That's my reading of it anyway.

Comment: @2501 Certainly with `unsigned char data[500]; function(data);`, `data` is _converted_ from an array 500 of `unsigned char` to a pointer to `unsigned char` in becoming the argument for `function()`.  C11 §6.3.2.1 3

Comment: @M.M Q should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a try at this:

```
unsigned char* des;
des = malloc(500 * sizeof(unsigned char));
strncpy(des, data, 500);
```

Then you should be able to call:

```
func(des);
```

Comment: This will corrupt the data if it wasn't a null-terminated string  (OP didn't specify that - the question is underspecified)